# Operator overload for [] operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Why would you need to overload the [] operator? I have never come across a practical scenario where this was necessary. Can somebody tell me a practical use case for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Err.. `std::vector<t>`, `std::basic_string<t>`, `std::map<k, v>`, and `std::deque<t>` ?

I used this for a class representing a registry key, where `operator[]` returned an object representing a registry value with the string between []s.

See also, the [Spirit Parser Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_Parser_Framework), which uses [] for semantic actions.

Answer (score 4):

Any *indexable* container can usefully define `operator[]` to become usable in any template that uses `[]`-syntax indexing.

You don't *need* that syntax sugar if you're not doing generic programming -- it may **look** nice, but, cosmetics apart, you could always define specific named methods such as `getAt`, `setAt`, and the like, with similar and simpler-to-code functionality.

However, generic programming is at the core of modern C++... and it bears an eerie resemblance to "compile-time, type-safe duck typing" (I'm biased towards such peculiar terminology, of course, having had a part in shaping it -- cfr [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#History);-).

Just as you should try to use, e.g., prefix-`*` to mean "dereferencing" for all kinds of iterators and other pointer-like types (so they can be duck-typingly substituted for pointers in a template!), so similarly you should strive to define `operator[]` in container types where it makes sense, just so they can be duck-typingly substituted for arrays in appropriate templates.

Answer (score 3):

It is useful if you implement almost any type of container that provides random access (or at least some form of keyed access) to its elements (e.g., consider `std::vector`).

Answer (score 1):

If you write a class that inherits from another class that implements the [] operator, you might want to overwrite the [] operator, such as `std::vector` or `std::string`. If you don't do this, your class may not work as the user expects, as your class will implicitly inherit the parent's implementation of [].

Answer (score 1):

Well, several STL containers give some examples - `vector<>` overloads it to make it act like an array.  `map<>` for example provides the `operator[]` overload to provide an 'associative array'.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not strictly necessary, it is incredibly useful in making user-defined containers or strings behave like builtin arrays or C strings. This cuts down on verbosity a lot (for example, in Java, you would have to use x.getElementAt(i) while in C++ you can use x[i]; similarly, in Java you need x.compareTo(y)<0, while in C++ you can achieve the same thing using x < y). It is syntactic sugar... but it is very, very tasty.